# definition of being closed under some operation

Tags: real-analysis

how do we define a set to be closed under some operation? 
for example how is this theorem true?
Let G denote the family of all open subsets of the real numbers and F the family of all closed subsets of the real numbers.
1-G is closed under arbitrary unions and finite intersections.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  A set is closed if its complement is open.  A family is closed under intersection/union if the intersection/union of members is in the family

Comment: I think the confusion is the use of the word "closed".  In terms of operations an operation $\circ$ is "closed if $a\circ b$ is always defined and has a value that is part of universe set the operation is acting on.  This has *nothing* to do with the meaning a *set* being "closed" which means something entirely different.

Comment: well the lines above are not made by myself they are the lines of textbook real analysis by bruckner and the word close seems very tricky for me

Comment: Can you write *EXACTLY* what the text said.  What does "$1 - G$" mean.  The way I interpret it is how I answered.  $G$ is set of sets.  No topology is given.  But if we consider $\cup$ and $\cap$ be an operations. If $A_1, A_2,....\in G$ are open sets then $\cup A_i $ is an open set.  So $\cup A_i \in G$.  So as *operation*, $\cup$ is "closed" mean the union of elements of $G$ (open sets) is also an element of $G$ (that is, is also an open set).

Comment: In other words.... you can rewrite the theorem as Jose Carlos Santos did in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

What the statement concerning $G$ *means* is:

1. If $A$ is a set of open subsets of $\mathbb R$, then $\bigcup_{S\in A}S$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$;
2. If $A$ is a *finite* set of open subsets of $\mathbb R$, then $\bigcap_{S\in A}S$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Ooh... bad terminology.

A set being $\color{blue}{open/closed}$ is an *entirely* different concept and has nothing whatsoever with an operation being $\color{red}{closed}$.

An operation, $\circ$ and a collection $C$,  is $\color{red}{closed}$ if for any $A, B\in C$ , then $A\circ B$ is defined and is in $C$.

Example:  the operation $+$ on $\mathbb N$ is $\color{red}{closed}$, because for and $a,b \in \mathbb N$ then $a+b \in \mathbb N$.  But the operation $-$ on $\mathbb N$ is *not* $\color{red}{closed}$, because for $5,7\in \mathbb N$ we have $5-7\not \in \mathbb N$.  But $-$ is $\color{red}{closed}$ on $\mathbb Z$ because for any $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ then $a-b \in \mathbb Z$.  But $\div$ is not closed on $\mathbb Z$ because for any integers $a,b$ it need not be that $a\div b \in \mathbb Z$.  But $\div$ is $\color{red}{closed}$ on $\mathbb Q\setminus\{0\}$ because if $a,b \in \mathbb Q$ and $a\ne 0, b\ne 0$ then $a\div b\in \mathbb Q$ and $a\div b \ne 0$.

Also an operation may be $\color{red}{closed}$ for a finite number of operations but not an infinite number.  For example $+$ on $\mathbb Z$ is closed under a finite number of opperations as for any $a_1, a_2, a_3,......., a_n\in \mathbb Z$ then $a_1 + a_2+a_3 + ...... + a_n \in \mathbb Z$.  But $+$ is *not* $\color{red}{closed}$ under an infinite number of operations as for $a_1, a_2, a_3,......, a_n$ is an infinite number of integers, it does not follow that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ is an integer (or even defined).  Certainly $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 1$ is not an integer (it's not even a real number).

..... Any hoo....

So the question is $G = \{$ all $\color{blue}{open}$ sets of $\mathbb R\}$ and the operations are $\cup$ (finite or infinite) and $\cap$ (finitely many times.

The question is are those operations $\color{red}{closed}$?

Or in other words if $A_1, A_2, A_3, .....$ are $\color{blue}{open}$ sets then is $A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3 \cup.... $ always $\color{blue}{open}$?   And if $A_1, A_2, .... A_n$ are $\color{blue}{open}$ sets is $A_1\cap A_2 \cap ..... \cap A_n$ always $\color{blue}{open}$.

Comment: You misspoke. An operation is not closed. A set is closed *under* the operation.

Comment: you mean a set cant be closed under for example arbitrary union?

Comment: No.  "open" doesn't mean "not closed".  You could have the sets $(k, k+2)$ where $k$ is an integer.  The union is $\cup_{k\in \mathbb Z} (k, k+2) = \mathbb R$.  That is closed *and* open.  I am saying that an arbitrary union of open sets will be an open set.

Comment: @TedShifrin you may be correct but *WHAT* set is closed under *what* operation and what does being "closed under arbitrary unions and finite intersections" mean?  Arbrary unions and finite intersections with *what* sets?  The statement is unclear.  As is $1-G$.  .... I simply interpretted this in the way that seemed to make the must sense.

Comment: thanks very much@fleablood you saved my life